# Some featurePHP Fatal error: Cannot redeclare GuzzleHttp\uri_template()

Tags: php, zend-framework2, codeception

I was trying to write unit testing using codeception in existing zend framework project. We are using s3 clients also for upload and download files. aws.phar file and codeception guzzlehttp getting conflicted, how could I avoid it?

When I run tests I got the following output
[image]

Comment: Don't use phar file, add codeception as dev dependency to composer.json

Comment: Did you solved this?

Comment: Not yet, but you can resolve this by upgrading aws sdk @AnkitJain